# Getting ordered substrings

Tags: string, python-3.x

If I have a list "abbabaabbaba" and I want to find the ordered occurences of some substrings "ab", "bb", I can do multiple .find() calls like this:

```
def foo(string, substrings):
    tuples = []
    for substring in substrings:
        string_copy = string
        while string_copy.find(substring) != -1:
            index = string_copy.find(substring)
            string_copy = string_copy[index:]
            tuples.append((index, substring))
    return sorted(tuples)
```

but is there possibly a shorter way? Something like:

```
def bar(string, substring):
    return ((index, substring) for substring in string.find(substring) if index != -1)
```

(but works)

Example:
`foo("abbabaabbaba", ["ab", "bb])`
`>>> [(0, "ab"), (1, "bb"), (3, "ab"), (6, "ab"), (7, "bb"), (9, "ab")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I allowed to use the [hot new `regex` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/)?

```
import regex

def foo(string, substrings):
    pattern = '(' + '|'.join(regex.escape(s) for s in substrings) + ')'
    return [(match.start(0), match.groups(1)[0])
            for match in regex.finditer(pattern, string, overlapped=True)]

foo("abbabaabbaba", ["ab", "bb"])
# -> [(0, 'ab'), (1, 'bb'), (3, 'ab'), (6, 'ab'), (7, 'bb'), (9, 'ab')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list comprehension` and `string slicing` like this example:

```
def get_occurrence(a, args, step=2):
    return [(k, a[k:k+step]) for k in range(len(a)) if a[k:k+step] in args]

a = "abbabaabbaba"
occurrences = get_occurrence(a, ['ab', 'bb'])
print(occurrences)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 'ab'), (1, 'bb'), (3, 'ab'), (6, 'ab'), (7, 'bb'), (9, 'ab')]
```

Comment: This only works in the special case where all substrings are of the same length.

Comment: Well, this is why i used `step` as an argument to handle the length of the substrings. Otherwise, with this approach you need to loop again over the string and modify the length each time.